# How do I get rows in SQL that have a value in a column that is 20 percent higher than the column average?

Tags: sql, subquery

So I am working in an SQL tutorial that is asking to find the states that have percentage of impaired drivers that is 20% higher than the average across all states. The percentage is represented by percentage points between 0-100.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT state, percent_alcohol_impaired 
FROM playground.bad_drivers
WHERE percent_alcohol_impaired - 20 >
        (SELECT AVG(percent_alcohol_impaired)
         FROM playground.bad_drivers)
LIMIT 100
```

The tutorial did not execute my query. Is this not a good way (or is there a better way) to get states above the average? TIA.

Comment: Seems okay to me :) You can/should create a little test table and run it (i.e. because "the tutorial did not execute my query" does not mean you can't do it).

Comment: might be an issue with the tutorial. it's driving me up the wall. thanks for replying!

Comment: Note that there is a difference between percentage and percentage points.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Is QUALIFY clause available?)

Comment: jarlh, it's from a tutorial from www.dataexpert.io/question. thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that `AVG` is the mean, not the median. Looks like you want a windowed `AVG(percent_alcohol_impaired) OVER ()` and then put that in a subquery/derived table and filter on the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT state, percent_alcohol_impaired  
FROM playground.bad_drivers 
WHERE percent_alcohol_impaired > 1.2 * (SELECT AVG(percent_alcohol_impaired) FROM playground.bad_drivers) 
LIMIT 100;
```

You should multiply the average percentage by 1.2 to find 20% higher than the average, and then compare it to the percentage of impaired drivers in each state.

Comment: yo! this worked for the tutorial. thank you!